# Using Laravel casts and mutators at the same time

Tags: php, laravel, attributes, mutators, ksort

This is part of my Role model:

```
namespace App;

use App\Traits\Permissions;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    use Permissions;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'permissions' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

This is my Permissions trait:

```
namespace App\Traits;

trait Permissions
{
    public function setPermissionsAttribute($permissions)
    {
        ksort($permissions);

        $this->attributes['permissions'] = $permissions;
    }
    /**
     * Adds a permission.
     *
     * @param  string $permission
     * @param  bool $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function addPermission($permission, $value = true)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($permission, $this->getAttribute('permissions'))) {
            $this->setAttribute('permissions', array_merge($this->getAttribute('permissions'), [$permission => $value]));
        }
    }
}
```

This will throw the following exception:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 769:
Array to string conversion (SQL: update `roles` set `permissions` = 1 where `id` = 46526e77-98b8-4126-aaae-7e109c7ea227)
```

If I print the `$permissions` variable after the `ksort` operation it correctly has the permissions array:

```
array:1 [
  "do.this" => true
]
```

If I remove the `setPermissionsAttribute` function it properly serializes the array into json and stores it in the database.

Am I doing something wrong or it's just not possible to use both these features?

Comment: did you try in setPermissionsAttribute just return the value?

Comment: @AmirBar Yes, it just won't do anything.

Answer (score 9):

When an attribute is get from the model, the mutateAttribute function is called before the castAttribute. You can check the code behind [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e6c8aa0e39d8f91068ad1c299546536e9f25ef63/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L338)

But you can call the castAttribute function in the mutator

```
 public function getPermissionsAttribute($value) {
    $p = $this->castAttribute('permissions', $value);
    ksort($p);
    return $p;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```php
public function setPermissionsAttribute($value): void
{
    $value['default']['value'] = true; // add, fill, remove, cast, sort etc..

    if ($value !== null && $this->isJsonCastable('permissions')) {
        $value = $this->castAttributeAsJson('permissions', $value);
    }
    $this->attributes['permissions'] = $value;
}
```

This proposal is more strict with Laravel's code base.

Answer (score 1):

`$cast` is also sort of a mutator itself. It doesnt make sense to have both any way. You should define another field that is based on the `permissions` attribute.

Comment: Imagine that you need to have an array type cast, but want to set a default value in case the array is empty.